# After clicking edit, it only allows me to edit one cell in that row and not the rest of the cells

Tags: jquery, html-table

Problem I am having

After I place an order, I want to click edit and be able to edit each cell in the row the edit button is located. However, it is only letting me edit the subtotal cell and not the rest of the cells. I did an alert in my Jquery code to see if I was picking up the right cells, but nothing showed up.

https://jsfiddle.net/f1achp5s/5/

I would appreciate any suggestions

HTML:

```
<div>
<main>
<br>
<form>
    <fieldset>

    <!--asks for name-->
    <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" />

    <br><br> 
    Drink Order:    
    <!--asks for coffee type-->
    <select name="drinkType" id="drinkType">
        <option value="#">Select Drink</option>
        <option value="0">Tea  $2.25</option>
        <option value="1">Coke  $2.50</option>
        <option value="2">Coffee  $2.75</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <label for="subtotal">Subtotal :</label>
    <input type="text" id="subtotal" disabled>
    <br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="placeOrderBtn" value="Place Order">    

    <br><br>

    </fieldset>
</form>
<br>
<h3 class = "hiddenReceipt">Receipt</h3>
<br>   

<table id = "receiptOrders">  
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Item Number</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
          <th>Edit/Save</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// if errors JavaScript will stop running
"use strict";

// Global Variables
var amt = 0; 
var itemNumber; // for receipt purposes

// arrays
var drinkCosts = [2.25, 2.50, 2.75]; // costs of each drink type
var namesInputsHolder =[]; // holds each customer's name
var subtotalHolder = []; // holds each customer's subtotal

// ready event: short way
$(function() {    
     // change
     $("select").change(processOrder); // select tags

     // calculates total cost
     $("#placeOrderBtn").click(function() {
         if ($("#drinkType").val() == "#") {
            alert ("Please select a drink type");
      } else {
         var nameInput = $("#nameInput").val(); // gets id: name value from HTML page
         var drink = parseInt($("#drinkType").val()); // gets id: drinkType value from HTML page
         var totalList = 0; 
         var subtotal = parseFloat($("#subtotal").val());
         subtotal = subtotal.toFixed(2);  // converts to string, 2 numbers after decimal

         // adds new item to the end of the array using push method
         namesInputsHolder.push(nameInput); // adds nams

         subtotalHolder.push(subtotal); // adds subtotal cost

         // i retrieves each element from the array
         for (var i = 0; i < namesInputsHolder.length; i++) { 
             totalList = "<tr><td></td><td class='editableText'>" +   namesInputsHolder[i] + "</td><td>" + subtotalHolder[i] + "</td><td><input type='button' value='Edit' class='editBtn'><input type='button' value='Save' class='saveBtn'></td></tr>";    
           }

         $("#receiptOrders > tbody").append(totalList); // table: tbody: children
         }

    // edits information
    $(".editBtn").click(function() { 
        $(this).hide(); // hides edit button
        $(this).next(".saveBtn").show(); // displays save button

        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
          $("tr").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false); 
          $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);
          $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "#c4c7c6"});
        });
    });

    // saves information
    $(".saveBtn").click(function() {
        $(this).hide(); // hides save button
        $(this).prev(".editBtn").show(); // displays edit button
        $(this).prop("contenteditable", false);
        $("td").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false); 
    });
    }); // end places order click

}); // end of ready event handler

var processOrder = function() {
// declaring local variables
var amt = 0;
var drink = parseInt($("#drinkType").val()); // gets id: drinkType value from HTML page

// shows output 

//calls the function 
var subtotal = drinkType(drink);
subtotal = parseFloat(subtotal);
// val() returns string, need to parse it into number first
$("#subtotal").val(subtotal.toFixed(2)); 

};

// matches each drink type to each price
// gets amount
var drinkType = function(inDrink) {
    var amt = 0;
    switch(inDrink) {
        case 0:
            amt = drinkCosts[0]; // Tea
            break;
        case 1:
           amt = drinkCosts[1]; // Coke  
           break;
        case 2:
           amt = drinkCosts[2]; // Coffee
           break;
    }
    return amt;
};
```

Comment: On Q2: You should use .html() instead of .val() on line 70. What are you doing with the input variable on line 68? This is not a valid jQuery selector. There are many, many more coding errors in your code. But I don't really want to rewrite the entire thing. It would be good if you try to isolate  and replicate a single issue and post that as a question. Hope it helps ;).

Comment: Next time: please fromat your code. It's realy hard to read it if all the code is not indented.

Comment: Sorry I read on the instructions that I had to indent my code 4 spaces.  I didn't know that I could indent further.  Thank you for not voting down my question.  I am new to jQuery.  I don't want you to rewrite my code for me.  However, you mentioned there are many coding errors in my code.  Can you give me another example of what is wrong with my code so I know what to fix? (i.e. html to val).  I will remove that variable.  My goal: After I place the order, I need to go back and change the name. I click on edit, the nameInput cell becomes editable so I can make changes.  I value your opinion.

Comment: I updated my code, but still cannot get it work.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Originally my code was:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
    $("td").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false); 
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);
    $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "#c4c7c6"});
});
```

And I changed it to:

Originally my code was:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
    $("td").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false); 
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);
    $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "#c4c7c6"});
});
```

I updated my code and jsFiddle